# Using WebAssembly to call Web API methods

Tags: webassembly

Is it possible to use [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) with WebAssembly? If so, how? I'm more interested in the [Navigator interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

*How* to do call JavaScript APIs when using a WebAssembly toolchain is up to that specific toolchain. It's effectively a form of FFI: from C++ code it looks like you're calling an external function, but the toolchain bridges to the embedder (here, the browser's JavaScript). A few examples:

- [C++ with Emscripten](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html)
- [SDL2](https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2)
- [html5.h](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/html5.h.html)
- [OpenGL / WebGL / OpenGL ES / OpenGL ES 2.0](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/multimedia_and_graphics/OpenGL-support.html)
- [Unity scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/)

Toolchains such as Emscripten automatically generate an `importObject` for `WebAssembly.instantiate` (along with `.html` and `.js` files)/ Most of the internal WebAssembly details are therefore usually hidden (I document them below).

This design allows you to call any JavaScript code, not just JavaScript APIs. You can therefore call your own JavaScript code from WebAssembly. Toolchains simply make it easier to handle common sets of web APIs, sometimes in a cross-platform manner, e.g. [SDL2](https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2) does audio, keyboard, mouse, joystick, and graphics.

## Internal Details

WebAssembly's [JavaScript API](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md) allows you to pass [an `importObject`](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md#webassemblyinstance-constructor) to the `WebAssembly.Instantiate` constructor and the `WebAssembly.instantiate` function:

```
new Instance(moduleObject [, importObject])

Promise<{module:WebAssembly.Module, instance:WebAssembly.Instance}>
    instantiate(BufferSource bytes [, importObject])
```

The WebAssembly [binary format](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md) contains an [import section](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md#import-section) where you (through a compiler such as LLVM) declare the imports which it'll use. Each of these imported fields is looked up in the `importObject`, and the functions [can be invoked](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/Semantics.md#calls) through WebAssembly's `call` and `call_indirect` opcode.

You can therefore call arbitrary JavaScript, which in turn can call any web API you want. In the future, WebAssembly may [gain capabilities which allow the embedder expose APIs directly](http://webassembly.org/docs/gc/), in a browser embedding this could include the DOM, canvas, events, etc.

Comment: Has these capabilities since been added? I.e. is this answer in need of an update?

Comment: @oligofren seems not yet https://github.com/WebAssembly/proposals/issues/16 ; Can pass functions through "env" configuration for instance. See "Call JavaScript functions from C/C++" here: https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html