# Modify canvas from wasm

Tags: html, canvas, webassembly

Is it possible to efficiently modify the html5 canvas from web assembly?

Update:

```
var imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, w, h)
var buffer = imageData.data.buffer;  // ArrayBuffer
```

Could be the way if the buffer is writable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using WebAssembly to call Web API methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904053/using-webassembly-to-call-web-api-methods)

Comment: You get that error because you forgot to write the situation and what you have tried. It's not enough to ask your question in one sentence without any proof of research

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, not in this stage of WebAssembly and web-api development.
With `context.getImageData` you get a new `ImageData` object with a new buffer which must be copied once again in the memory's buffer of your WebAssembly instance.
But if you don't need to read from canvas, only to write, you can allocate the `ImageData.data` in the memory of your WebAssembly instance. Use ImageData constructor

```
imageData = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(waInstance.export.memory.buffer, byteOffset, width*height*4), width, height)
```

`imageData` has a pointer to your data. On every rendering, do your work in WebAssembly and use the same `imageData` in `context.putImageData(imageData)`, doing only once a big data copy per cycle.

Comment: So how would you determine the desired value of `byteOffset` here?

Comment: Is it still true two years later that we can't read from the canvas in wasm?

Comment: Not yet. From https://github.com/WebAssembly/proposals in Phase 3 are "Reference Types" but you will still need to copy bytes and "Bulk memory operations" which will speed the copying process.

Answer (score 6):

WebAssembly instances typically have a linear memory area which is exposed to the JavaScript API as an arraybuffer. This can either be allocated in JS and passed in when the WebAssembly instance is created, or the WebAssembly instance can create it and export it to the JS code. Either way the arraybuffer can be used to efficiently copy data into and out of a Canvas element (using createImageData, getImageData and putImageData).

Comment: So memory has to be copied, which is not as efficient as directly writing to the bitmap, correct?

Comment: @Anona112 I suspect right now you will need to copy (TypedArray.of and/or TypedArray.set should be pretty efficient). I suspect at some point a method similar to structured cloning will be available for use between Canvas and WebAssembly (and this may in fact work now but it's not well documented if it is)

Answer (score 4):

1. Anyway, you will have to copy pixels to `WebAssembly.Memory` instance. Then modify and copy back.
2. I don't know why, but `Uint8Array.set()` is not fast in latest Chrome. It's better to recast data to 32 bit (`new Uint32Array(your_uint8array)`), and then use `Uint32Array.set()` to copy.
3. Keep in mind, that canva's `.getImageData()`/`.setImageData()` are not fast. Probably, because they do alpha premultiply and other things.

To summarize things: your most speed loss will be in .getImageData/.setImageData, and that can't be avoided. Other things have workarounds.

If compare with optimized JS, wasm will give you 10-20% of benefits, not too much.

Answer (score 1):

I understand a solution has been accepted, but in case someone else lands here looking for an alternative I'll post anyways.

I don't actively participate in the development of the wasm-bindgen tool for rust, but its currently able to modify the canvas element through the web-sys crate. The code shown below is taken from the link on the wasm-bindgen book page.

```
use std::f64;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;

#[wasm_bindgen(start)]
pub fn start() {
    let document = web_sys::window().unwrap().document().unwrap();
    let canvas = document.get_element_by_id("canvas").unwrap();
    let canvas: web_sys::HtmlCanvasElement = canvas
        .dyn_into::<web_sys::HtmlCanvasElement>()
        .map_err(|_| ())
        .unwrap();

    let context = canvas
        .get_context("2d")
        .unwrap()
        .unwrap()
        .dyn_into::<web_sys::CanvasRenderingContext2d>()
        .unwrap();

    context.begin_path();

    // Draw the outer circle.
    context
        .arc(75.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, f64::consts::PI * 2.0)
        .unwrap();

    // Draw the mouth.
    context.move_to(110.0, 75.0);
    context.arc(75.0, 75.0, 35.0, 0.0, f64::consts::PI).unwrap();

    // Draw the left eye.
    context.move_to(65.0, 65.0);
    context
        .arc(60.0, 65.0, 5.0, 0.0, f64::consts::PI * 2.0)
        .unwrap();

    // Draw the right eye.
    context.move_to(95.0, 65.0);
    context
        .arc(90.0, 65.0, 5.0, 0.0, f64::consts::PI * 2.0)
        .unwrap();

    context.stroke();
}
```

The canvas object is accessible from the rust code that is converted into web-assembly. There are many ways to invoke the web-assembly code, but the suggested one for this example is an index.js file with these contents, and a bundler like webpack.

```
import("path/to/wasm/canvas/code").catch(console.error)
```

For end to end demonstration of this follow this link as reference.

[canvas hello world](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/examples/2d-canvas.html)

Comment: I believe this just makes WASM call a generated JavaScript function, which does the Canvas API calls.