# Is it faster to draw a series images on a Canvas with WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, webassembly, emscripten

I want to ask if it's faster and more memory efficient to draw a series of images into a canvas using WebAssembly/WASM?

I'm asking this since I have tested to draw series of images (animation) both in the main UI and with web workers. For few canvases (*1-5 canvases*) the performance is bearable, however for more canvases (*like 20-25*) the scenario gets a little different, rendering becomes slow motion.

**Here's the code in main UI:**

```
const videoDecoder = new Worker("videoDecoder.js");
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
videoDecoder.postMessage({ action: 'init', canvas: offscreen }, [offscreen] );
```

**Here's my web worker:**

```
onmessage = async function (e) {
    const blob = e.data;
    blob.arrayBuffer().then(arrayBuffer => {
        const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        for(;;;) {
           const offsetIdx = ...;
           const endIdx = ...;
           const jpegArray = uint8Array.slice(offsetIdx, endIdx);
           const blob = new Blob([jpegArray], {type: "image/jpeg"});
           drawImage(blob);
        }
    }
}

async function drawImage(blob) {
    const bmp = await createImageBitmap(blob);
    context.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
    bmp.close();
}
```

This works fine it can render the images to the browser from web worker, but as mentioned, at 1-5 canvases it is still smooth, but with more canvases the rendering in the browser gets very slow.

So I want to ask **is it faster to draw a series images on a Canvas with WebAssembly**? Or there will be no theoretical performance gain compared to doing it now with the  web worker approach?

Comment: webassembly has no access to DOM - a canvas is part of the DOM - so, no, it would not be possible

Comment: @jaromanda-x According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806037/modify-canvas-from-wasm and other blog articles I found online, its possible to "draw" to the canvas from WASM using shared memory.

Comment: well, try it and see for yourself

Comment: My concern is mainly in the performance aspect which before I try to "rewrite" my web worker into C++ for wasm I want to ask if anyone have experience how much performance gain vs doing it on Javascript alone--or there is none so I would like to know upfront if there's a point on taking up the task on doing  WASM at all.

Comment: Here's a demo: https://www.hellorust.com/demos/canvas/index.html

Comment: You can write in the ArrayBuffer from WASM, but you'd still have to `putImageData` from the main or Worker. From your code, the seemingly logical part that should be moved to WASM is the hidden part in `for(;;;) {
           const offsetIdx = ...;
           const endIdx = ...;`. The slowest part though is probably `drawImage()`. If you wish to pass that to WASM, you'd need to implement the Image decoder yourself. B.t.w. bypassing account's suspension by using an other account is quite a questionable practice...

Answer (score 3):

WebAssembly may be faster for complex computation on a byte array, but the main JavaScript UI thread will still be doing the rendering of the `ArrayBuffer` to `canvas`.  As long as you're "reusing" `ArrayBuffer` instances by passing objects with the [`Transferable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) interface between main UI thread and WebWorker, you should be able to easily update the canvas performantly.

When rendering updates to multiple `canvas` objects, consider batching them within a [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) function to minimize repainting of the pixels in the browser. This should significantly improve browser frame rate performance.

Comment: So you mean, there's no significant performance gain from using Web Assembly vs web worker in this context?

Comment: It all depends on how much computation is occurring.  I always recommend A/B testing and measurements for all performance comparisons. Theoretically, WASM should be faster for more complex algorithms. Your slow motion may result from multiple repaints on the main UI thread

Comment: In my case, all the canvases are "rendered" in the web worker: `const offscreen = canvas[i].transferControlToOffscreen();` so the code left in the main UI thread is the passing of these canvases to web workers, and of course the instantiation of web workers. So there's no `requestAnimationFrame` in the case of the receiving app which renders 20 canvases. Everything comes from the websocket as bytes and goes to the Video decoder workers.

Comment: In fact here's the complete code that renders the canvases: https://gist.github.com/questionaut/8d01108cd6152495762b021d0e93b285

Answer (score 2):

> So I want to ask is it faster to draw a series images on a Canvas with WebAssembly?

WebAssembly can be faster than JavaScript, but it isn't always. It very much depends on the type of computation you are performing. Probably the greatest strength of WebAssembly is that the performance is predictable and constant. This blog post gives probably the most informative real-world performance results:

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/01/oxidizing-source-maps-with-rust-and-webassembly/

> Or there will be no theoretical performance gain compared to doing it now with the web worker approach?

The two methods are in no way mutually exclusive! You can run WebAssembly within a Web Worker and use shared memory (similar to a `SharedArrayBuffer`) to allow cross-thread access of your image data. This blog post gives an example of how WebAssembly can be used to compute an algorithm across multiple worker threads:

https://blog.scottlogic.com/2019/07/15/multithreaded-webassembly.html

In response to your specifics, a video decoders (which are typically written in C++) are a very good candidate for WebAssembly. I'd suggest creating multiple web workers, each with a WebAssembly-powered decoder.