# For managed languages, will the language runtime need to be embedded into the web assembly executable?

Tags: webassembly

If, for example, Microsoft created a WebAssembly target for .NET, would they need to embed the .NET runtime into the compiled binary? If they didn't, how would things like the garbage collector and base class libraries work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple answer: yes.**

To run any language in WebAssembly you have to embed its runtime into your binary. That's true of how Emscripten handles C++ (it embeds [musl libc](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/lib/libc/musl), [libc++](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/lib/libcxx), [libc++abi](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/lib/libcxxabi), [compiler-rt](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/lib/compiler-rt), and [pthread](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/lib/pthread) into your binary), as well as other languages.

---

**Longer, nuanced, answer:**

Done right and once available, GC [would be part of WebAssembly itself](http://webassembly.org/docs/gc/), but you can always embed a [Boehm GC](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/) at your own risk (scanning the stack in WebAssembly is extra tricky because locals aren't accessible within the VM!).

Not all languages VMs have GC though. They have a bunch of other functionality, some may even want their own [just-in-time compilation on top of WebAssembly](http://webassembly.org/docs/jit-library/).

Base class libraries are often just about objet layout, they translate pretty easily to WebAssembly. See [libc++abi](https://libcxxabi.llvm.org/spec.html) for what that means for C++.

That said the runtime doesn't have to be in **the** compiled binary. Two options:

1. Embed the runtime in JavaScript instead. You can implement significant code in JavaScript, say [chunks of a libc](https://github.com/jfbastien/musl/tree/wasm-prototype-1/arch/wasm32). A language VM's runtime isn't really different.
2. Embed the runtime in a separate, [dynamically-linked `.wasm` file](http://webassembly.org/docs/dynamic-linking/). This means multiple different `.wasm` file can share the runtime! Multiple websites can even share that `runtime.wasm` and hope to all cache-hit on compiled code (assuming [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) works out).

In fact, to do anything useful you *must* do at least some of 1.: WebAssembly doesn't define any APIs to the embedder. In a [web embedding](http://webassembly.org/docs/web/) the only way to do *anything at all* is to be called from JavaScript, and / or call into JavaScript, through WebAssembly's [`import` and `export` sections](http://webassembly.org/docs/modules/#imports). In that sense, JavaScript is your application's microkernel, offering capabilities to [communicate with the rest of the platform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40904287/3983557).

This gets tricky when your language runtime requires certain platform capabilities. For example, re-creating a platform's native UI library for the web is no small task. Much of a language's runtime can "just work", but some parts may be significant amounts of work.

Comment: How will trust work with regards to sharing dynamically-linked WASM files? Right now, caching is at the domain level, but if one domain could link against a runtime provided by another domain, doesn't that introduce some pretty fundamental trust issues?

Comment: @w.brian same as anything else on the Web: if you don't trust it be careful! Load it over https, and validate a checksum (or use SRI if available). In any case there's no guarantee that the browser will cache the content, or cache the compiled code, across origins. I expect that we'd do so if the usage becomes common though.