# Will WebAssembly make the Audio API and WebGL obsolete?

Tags: webassembly

My question now is how does WebAssembly affect the Audio Api and WebGL? I mean the Audio API is high level and relies on javascript so how does all the audio manipulation, midi etc work in webassembly? Do we directly work with the above mentioned APIs or do we use some other 3rd party library such as http://www.portaudio.com/ ? Same with WebGL, do we use WebGL or the C++ OpenGL interface directly now that we have low level access?

Comment: You still would have to write the audio and webgl part in javsascript, but can do the math and processing in webassembly

Comment: http://webassembly.org/docs/gc/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is very close to [this one on Web APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904053/using-webassembly-to-call-web-api-methods) with one difference: how are web APIs affected?

Web APIs aren't affected at all, WebAssembly needs to call to JavaScript. There are libraries which make this easier, such as [SDL2](https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2). Same with [GL](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/multimedia_and_graphics/OpenGL-support.html). You could also create your own wrappers instead of using pre-made ones.

In the long run WebAssembly may gain direct access to APIs without JavaScript, but at this point in time it [has very limited access](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md) on purpose: it made the design and implementation simpler. Emscripten was proof that this approach was minimally viable.